# MongoDB hosting, single-node or cluster set replicas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mlab

I was wondering does it changes something between the mlab single-node or cluster set replicas hosting for my application ( do i need to modify the code if i pick either of thoses. ) Or is it just the performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mLab's docs explain the difference: http://docs.mlab.com/plans/#single-vs-cluster-plans